# How to fetch primary key in Aerospike Node.js Client

Tags: node.js, aerospike

I'm trying to fetch all records along with Primary key from Aerospike.
I tried using client.query functionality as below

```
var query = client.query(aerospikeDBParams.dbName,"testRecords");
var stream = query.execute();
```

with this I'm getting all the fields except the Primary key.How can i get Primary key along with the other fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to actually store the primary key with the [record](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#records). The client and server locate the record using its digest, which the client hashes using the (namespace, set, primary-key) information. The default value for the key write policy is `Aerospike.policy.key.DIGEST`. You will need to explicitly set that to `Aerospike.policy.key.SEND` instead.

See the [Aerospike:module](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike.html) documentation. It contains this example:

```
// global policy, applied to all commands that do not override it
var config = {
  policies: {
    timeout: 100,
    retry: Aerospike.policy.retry.ONCE
  }
}

Aerospike.connect(config, (error, client) => {
  if (error) throw error

  var key = new Aerospike.Key('test', 'demo', 'k1')
  var record = {i: 1234}

  // override policy for put command
  var policy = {
    exists: Aerospike.policy.exists.CREATE,
    key: Aerospike.policy.key.SEND
  }

  client.put(key, record, {}, policy, (error) => {
    if (error && error.code === Aerospike.status.AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_EXISTS) {
      console.info('record already exists')
    } else if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    client.close()
  })
})
```

When the keys are stored with the record a query will return them.

Comment: That's the method to put key information to server. But query method return recordStream, that the data event only return (bins, meta), I can't find 'key'. It's ok to use java client thought.

Comment: @sel-fish, you are right: As of v2.0.3, the client's record stream `data` event does not include the record key. That's a [regression](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/issues/126) from the v1 client and I will fix this in the next patch release.